# .htaccess redirect to external URL while hiding redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess redirect to external URL while hiding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807925/htaccess-redirect-to-external-url-while-hiding-redirect)

Is there a way to rewrite to an external site while hiding the new address?

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.second-website.com/index.php\?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

The rule works perfectly for a page on the same server, but on a different server it changes the address as if I had used `[L,R=301]`.

EDIT:
I am using a reverse proxy, but getting a 500 error.

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://www.second-website.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://www.second-website.com/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a reverse proxy. It can be implemented in Apache using [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). You can use the [`P`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag if you already have a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Can you give an example? Or tell me what I am doing wrong? (see above)