# Using .htaccess Redirect 301 without changing URL in Address Bar

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I currently have a WordPress Multi-Site Network set up. The main website is located at `"http://safesideinc.com."` Then, there is another sub-domain `"http://danielgosek.safesideinc.com."`

I want the URL "http://safesideinc.com" to lead to `"http://safesideinc.com,"` and the URL `"http://danielgosek.com"` to lead to `"http://danielgosek.safesideinc.com."`

Using a 301 Redirect in .htaccess, I can achieve this. However, I would like it so that entering `"http://danielgosek.com"` in the URL bar leads to `"http://danielgosek.safesideinc.com."` WITHOUT CHANGING the URL displayed--in this case, the displayed URL should remain `"http://danielgosek.com."`

Are there any rules that could help me achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807925/htaccess-redirect-to-external-url-while-hiding-redirect

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, a **301** - Permanent Redirect, is an instruction to the BROWSER that the resource has moved permanently and the BROWSER should re-direct to the provided new URL.

If you don't want the URL to change you either need a Reverse proxy set-up between the two virtual hosts / domains, or if **danielgosek.com** is just an alias, same IP and served from the same Apache virtual host, you could use an internal rewrite.